# Pass query result from rails controller to javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a project which is based on ruby on rails and js in front end.In one of the controller I get the query result @sites which consists of many rows like
id         amount
NewYork    200
Seattle    10000
Toronto    30
...        ....

Now I want to pass this arrays of objects to the front end which is js.In the javascript, I want to get the amount of every id.So what should I do? To make it in json? Or pass it by html?
Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how you have the javascript configured to receive payloads. I have no clue how you have the front end shaped to receive it. Are you using a framework such as Angular or Ember?

Comment: Only d3.js .There is no framework @Antonio

Comment: It's hard to beat JSON. I would reference the documentation from this point.